# How to organize images for delivery performance in a website

Tags: performance, image, optimization

I've a website with listings and images associated with each listing.

I currently have images organized like this in the file system:

D:\Images\Original

D:\Images\Thumbnail

Each listing can have up to 12 images in the original size and in the thumbnail size.

I'm wondering how to best organized the images in the file system to get better performance in terms of locating the images for a listing.

I'm thinking about this organization:

**For listing with Id 101:**

D:\Images\Original\101

D:\Images\Thumbnail\101

**For listing with Id 102:**

D:\Images\Original\102

D:\Images\Thumbnail\102

etc.

In other words, each listing will have a folder (named after the listing Id). In that folder, you only have images for that particular listing.

Are there better ways to organize the listing images? I almost have 1 million images in total.

Comment: Better ways in what sense? What are you trying to optimize?

Comment: I want to reduce the time it takes for the system to locate an image in the file system. Locating an image in a folder with 500,000 image is probably slower than locating an image in a folder with 12 images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would keep related images together.  Otherwise you're creating a maintenance nightmare.  So:

```
D:\Images\102\imagename_raw.png
D:\Images\102\imagename_1024_786.png
D:\Images\102\imagename_40_40.png
```

And then

```
D:\Images\103\imagename_raw.png
D:\Images\103\imagename_1024_786.png
D:\Images\103\imagename_40_40.png
```

That way, everything is in one place, consistent and concise.